# draw.io removing extra white spaces

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I am trying to put words in a text inside a shape, but I am only allowed one white space between them, which makes them really hard to read since they are not a sentence, I was wondering if there is a way to list these words with enough space between them?

Answer (score 1):

You could change the shape label into an HTML label, that will preserve the whitespace. Go to *Format* → *Style* and add

```
html=1
```

to the end of that string and press OK. You'll then get the behavior you want.

And rather than do that every time, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to clone the shape to get a copy shape with the style.